# Typescript: Get the literal value from a generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, literals

Is it possible to get the literal value from a type? For example:

```
const createRecord = <T>(type: T, data: number) => ({ type, data })
const r = createRecord<'TYPE_1'>('TYPE_1', 101)

// The type of `r` is { type: "TYPE_1"; data: number; }
```

But I would like to omit the first parameter and simply write:

```
const createRecord = <T>(data: number) => ({ type: typeof T, data })
const r = createRecord<'TYPE_1'>(101)
```

Of course the previous example doesn't work because `typeof T` is a type, not a value.

Comment: It seems to me you are mixing the value with a literal type. You are returning an object so it is a value, a so the `type` property must have a value, not only a type, as you did with `data`. You can type the return of the function explicitly but then type will be `undefined` nonetheless. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function `createRecord` returns an object and an object is a value, so the `type` property must also have a value, not only a type. What you can do instead is let TypeScript infer the type for `T` from the value you give. TypeScript only infers a literal type if you constrained the generic type to `string` (or `number`, etc).

You can create the function like this:

```
const createRecord2 = <T extends string>(type: T, data: number) => ({ type, data })
```

and then you do

```
const r2 = createRecord2('TYPE_1', 101)

r2.type // type is inferred as 'TYPE_1'
```

Note that I don't specify the type for `T` at the call, it is deduced from the given argument.

See here the difference: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAlRp4BMYF4YAeAFQD4AKKATwAdEAuGEgGhh1WSbAFcBbAEaJ4ASgJkYFAN4wa9NhyjIYAXxEBYAFChIseAEYCcJKgxYQuCgHISATQAKAUQD6+q230AGfRs1aDAHRyiDAA9KGydCEAlhAw0WAAZsJIeMhx0PAJAOZaWjrQxihomNg4AExGpDCIAB5oYDgZUFlg2ZTBTKzsnNz8QqLikjLBCpyqvgV6lYQIxWZl5dZ2Tq7uMF4+eZrw5UFRYRHB8XEJyfCpMOkwNg4ublpAA)

Comment: I did that. The problem is that createRecord may have multiple generic types. And TypeScript doesn't allow me to omit the last type (T in this case). When I omit the T parameter, it says `Expected "n" types arguments, but got "n - 1"`.

Comment: Then maybe you should put a more complete example. The usual way to go is let TS infer all the types, but it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel mentioned in the previous message, we can infer the generic types from the parameters. The problem is that the function may contain multiple generic types, and TypeScript doesn't permit to omit some of them (you can omit all, however). So here's a workaround to the problem:

```
const createRecord = <S, T extends string>(type: T, data: S) => ({ type, data })
const r = createRecord('TYPE_1', 101)
// type of `r` is const r: { type: "TYPE_1"; data: number; }
```

Note that the generic types `T` and `S` are inferred from the parameters `type` and `data`. However you can't do this:

```
const createRecord = <S, T extends string>(type: T, data: S) => ({ type, data })
const r = createRecord<number>('TYPE_1', 101)
// Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

Also note that `T` **must to extends string** in order to obtain the string literal (otherwise, type would be simply `string`).